# Add a hyperlink to a view in a grid

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, view, controller

I'm trying to add a column in a table that has an hyperlink to another view carrying the data of that current row.

```
if (Model.Entries.Any())
{
@grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "table table-striped table-splited", mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
columns: grid.Columns(
        grid.Column("Request", "Request"),
        grid.Column("Response", "Response"),
        grid.Column("CustomerID", "Customer ID")));
}
```

My question is how do I do add the column with the hyperlink to my other view?

Answer (score 0):

```
          if (Model.Entries.Any())
       {
          @grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "table table-striped table-splited", mode: 
          WebGridPagerModes.All,
          columns: grid.Columns(
          grid.Column("Request", "Request"),
          grid.Column("Response", "Response"),
          grid.Column("CustomerID", "Customer ID")
          .RenderValueAs(o => Html.ActionLink(o.CustomerID, "TargetingNextView", new 
          { ID = o.CustomerID}));
       }
```

\ ur controller

```
      public ActionResult TargetingNextView(int id)
      {
      return View();
      }
```

Comment: I forgot to add that it is a webgridcolumn, the property rendervalueas is not defined for it